# Why are Visual Studio project properties not shared between users?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We have a WebApi2 project within a solution.

The solution has multiple startup projects and the WebApi2 project has a setting not to open any page. I set this settings and checkin the solution in TFS.

Other developers get the latest sources, but these settings are gone (or reset to default)?

Are these settings per-user settings and if yes, how can these settings be shared amongst users?

Comment: Some settings are shared, others are per-user. You can try checking in `.suo`/`.user` files alongside the `.sln` and `.XXproj` files but it tends to be more "annoying" than "useful" to enforce everyone sharing exactly one set of settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't share those properties. Visual Studio thinks some properties are user based, like what project to start when debugging, the build mode, etc.

This is just something they found most useful on a user basis, not on a project basis. You could put the `*.user` files in your version control system too. Then all user properties will be share too. You could also create a prebuild event that changes that `user` config file.

Answer (score 0):

The startup project is stored in the .suo file in Visual Studio. However, the .suo files have a bunch of other user-specific (and probably machine specific) cruft in them that make them not suitable for committing to source control.

However, there might be some options for you:

- [The slnStartupProject on github](https://github.com/michaKFromParis/slnStartupProject) can help if you use a command-line build script or train everyone to run this utility.
- [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2015/01/13/setup-startup-project-automatically-for-universal-apps.aspx) explains how you can influence the startup project in visual studio with some settings